# Using material-ui autocomplete with dividers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to add dividers between material-ui autocomplete options ?

I found only this workaround, but I don't think it's the best way to do it:

```
const options = [
    {
      label: 'Opt 1',
      value: 'OPT1'
    },
    {
      label: 'Divider',
      value: 'DIV',
      isDivider: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Opt 2',
      value: 'OPT2'
    },
    {
      label: 'Opt 3',
      value: 'OPT3'
    }
  ];

...

  // used to remove the opacity of disabled items (in my case dividers)
  autocompleteOption: {
    '&[aria-disabled="true"]': {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }

...

<Autocomplete
    options={options}
    multiple
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => isEqual(value, option)}
    classes={{
      option: classes.autocompleteOption
    }}
    getOptionDisabled={(option) => option.isDivider}
    renderOption={(option) => {
      if (option.isDivider) {
        return <Divider className={classes.divider} />;
      }

      return option.label;
     }}
     ...
 />
```

- added **isDivider** option where I need a divider
- added **getOptionDisabled** method to disaled divider options
- added some styling to remove the opacity of disabled items (dividers in my case)
- added **renderOption** to render dividers based on the **isDivider** prop

Do you have any other ideas ?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: just wanted to say I came to the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a dummy option, how about tagging options that should be followed by a divider?

For instance, say you want to add a divider between the third and forth option. Set `isDivider` to `true` for the third option

```
options[2].isDivider = true
```

and then inserting the `<Divider />` in the renderOption as follows:

```
renderOption={(props, option: any) => (
  <>
    <Li {...props}>{option.title}</Li>
    {option.isDivider ? <Divider /> : null}
  </>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouping. Groups can have a label or be custom rendered.

Labels:

```
<Autocomplete
 groupBy={option => option.styleId ? 'Style' : 'Font'}
 ...
```

[image: Autocomplete list with headers]

Dividers:

```
<Autocomplete
  renderGroup={params => (
    <li key={params.key}>
      <ul style={{ padding: 0 }}>{params.children}</ul>
        {params.key !== 'your last group' && <Divider />}
    </li>
  )}
  ...
```

[image: Autocomplete list with dividers]

Answer (score 0):

This could be done via CSS, ':last-of-type' selector

[image]